# How to have raphael graph on each element with a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I just started looking into Raphael, and every tutorial said that you may draw on an element by doing this:

```
element = Raphael(elementId);
```

Now say I have a bunch of `<div>` all with `class='icon'` and I wish to use Raphael to draw the same image on all occurrences of of this div. How would I do so?

Comment: It might be a better option to export it as an image and just replace the divs with images. but i'll answer any way, one sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is set up an 'each' function and loop over all of the icons and draw on each one. like so,

```
var papers = []
$(".icon").each(function(index, element){
  papers.push(Raphael(element, "100%", "100%"));
  papers[index].rect(x,y,height,width); //replace this with the code you will use to draw your icon.

});
```

That should work, but comment if you have any issues.

Comment: Cool thanks. You do make a good point, I might just end up switching it to an image instead.